# second internal drive mounting for nobody/nogroup

Tags: permissions, mount

`Ubuntu 20.10`

This has only recently started happening. Before today (the first I noticed I don't have write permission on the drive.) I have had free access to the drive.

The mount point is owned as

```
root@acer:/# ls -l / | grep mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root          4096 Feb 16 03:57 mnt
root@acer:/# ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxr-x 2 root users 4096 Feb 16 03:57 3T
```

The fstab entry is

```
UUID=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-123456789 /mnt/3T ext4 defaults 0 0
```

After mounting via fstab, the ownership is

```
drwxrwxr-x 44 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 16 09:04 3T/
```

After mounting from commandline using /dev id :

```
root@acer:/mnt# mount /dev/sda /mnt/3T
root@acer:/mnt# ll
drwxrwxr-x 44 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 16 09:04 3T/
```

Checking the mounts

```
# mount -f
/dev/sda on /mnt/3T type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

And the journal

```
journalctl 
Feb 28 16:22:04 acer systemd[1084]: mnt-3T.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 28 16:22:04 acer systemd[1]: mnt-3T.mount: Succeeded.
Feb 28 16:22:13 acer kernel: EXT4-fs (sda): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
(null)
```

Comment: Can I confirm that you're mounting the *device* `/dev/sda` rather than a *partition* such as `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: @Matigo There is a single partition on the drive so there is no number.  Keep in mind that this system has been working as is for a couple years now.